# Simulink Desktop Real-Time (R2017b): data logging fails with GUIDE application

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I have a Simulink model that runs in External mode using Simulink Desktop-Real Time. The model contains scopes for data logging and for displaying signal traces. For some reason, the scopes don't work when I launch the model programmatically from a GUIDE application. In other words, no data log files are generated, and the display scopes don't show anything. However, if I launch the model programmatically from a simple Matlab script (no UI) then the scopes do work as expected, that is, I do get files and can see the signal traces. Other than the scopes, the model runs correctly from GUIDE, i.e. it can talk to hardware through the I/O blocks, etc. I never had this problem with R2015a but now I have it with R2017b.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [Running Applications from the Command Line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sldrt/ug/run-application-from-matlab-command-line.html), I suspect you are missing the following second step:

```
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationMode','external') % only needed if the model isn't set up for External Mode already
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','connect') % <- you are missing this
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','start')
>> set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','stop')
```

Comment: That is not the case, otherwise the model wouldn't work at all. It is only the scopes that are failing for some reason.

Comment: I just tested a minimal working example, and found that the problem occurs when the model model is launched from a Matlab UI, but not when it is launched from a simple Matlab script.

Comment: That sounds like some sort of Workspace issue.  Does it work when run from a simple function?  Is the model using variables that the script defines in the Base Workspace, but the function/UI does not?

Comment: No, the model reads its Workspace data from a MAT-file. Bear in mind that the real-time model actually works in both cases (running from an UI and running from a simple script). I can verify that easily because I use the model to operate hardware (a simple robot). It is only the scopes that fail when the model runs from the UI.